# Flutter Google Map API Issue when App Runs

Tags: api, google-maps, flutter

I currently developing a app  for tracking the patients. So I use google maps and I have get the API key from the google cloud platform and restrict the key as for the Android Map SDK

then I changed the android manifest.xml and ios runners and plist

when I run the application it shows the following errot

```
E/flutter ( 4675): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create an already created platform view, view id: 0
E/flutter ( 4675):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:85)
E/flutter ( 4675):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:96)
E/flutter ( 4675):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:60)
E/flutter ( 4675):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:231)
E/flutter ( 4675):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:93)
E/flutter ( 4675):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:642)
E/flutter ( 4675):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 4675):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/flutter ( 4675):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
E/flutter ( 4675):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
E/flutter ( 4675):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 4675):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/flutter ( 4675):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/flutter ( 4675): , null)
E/flutter ( 4675): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
E/flutter ( 4675): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:33)
E/flutter ( 4675): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4675): #2      AndroidViewController._create (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:640:54)
E/flutter ( 4675): #3      AndroidViewController.setSize (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:557:14)
E/flutter ( 4675): #4      RenderAndroidView._sizePlatformView (package:flutter/src/rendering/platform_view.dart:174:29)
E/flutter ( 4675): #5      RenderAndroidView.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/platform_view.dart:155:5)
E/flutter ( 4675): #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1703:9)
E/flutter ( 4675): #7      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
E/flutter ( 4675): #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
E/flutter ( 4675): #9      MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:163:11)
E/flutter ( 4675): #10     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:477:7)
E/flutter ( 4675): #11     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:232:7)
E/flutter ( 4675): #12     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:391:14)
E/flutter ( 4675): #13     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
E/flutter ( 4675): #14     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
E/flutter ( 4675): #15     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
E/flutter ( 4675): #16     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
E/flutter ( 4675): #17     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1232:11)
E/flutter ( 4675): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
E/flutter ( 4675): #19     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
E/flutter ( 4675): #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
E/flutter ( 4675): #21     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
E/flutter ( 4675): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
E/flutter ( 4675): #23     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
E/flutter ( 4675): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
E/flutter ( 4675): #25     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
E/flutter ( 4675): #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
E/flutter ( 4675): #27     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
E/flutter ( 4675): #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
E/flutter ( 4675): #29     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
E/flutter ( 4675): #30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rende
```

I have done everything for debugging this error(try for 10+ times). If you can help me out with this problem thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508799/flutter-google-maps-trying-to-create-an-already-created-platform-view-view-id) . It seems that you are encountering the same issue. There are answers on this post that may help you.

Comment: Yeah exactly. I refer them too. But I did so many things, like console commands and rebuild emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope I found the answer when run those commands `flutter clean` and `flutter pub cache repair` int he command line and it works fine. Other than that my emulator hasn't installed the google paly services. Then when I rebuild and run it. It works fine.

But google needs to take into consideration about those exceptions when implementing the next version of the API